# GWT restore visibility restrictions from uiBinder

Tags: java, gwt, visibility, restore, restrictions

Let's say I have some components with `visible="false"` property in my ui.xml file, and in my java code I showed some of those components. Is there any simple way/method to restore visibility restrictions stored in uiBinder, so I get the basic components configuration?

Answer (score 2):

No, UiBinder doesn't work that way. The `ui.xml` file is used at compile time to generate Java code for you. So your `visible="false"` will probably result in generating a call to `UiObject.setVisible`, etc. This code is run when you call `initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));`. If you want to "restore" your widget to this initial state set by UiBinder I'm afraid the only easy way is to instantiate the widget again - but I don't recommend this as it's usually a costly operation. It's better to just write a method that restores the fields to a predefined state - you could use this method to set the initial state too, instead of defining it (and duplicating, in a sense) in the UiBinder template. I'm assuming you have all the necessary fields accessible in your class (since you mentioned changing their visibility via Java code in your question), so you won't have to add a bunch of fields just to call `setVisibile` on them.

Comment: On second thought I decided to hold visibility restrictions in separate structure, so I can easily any time I need them. But thanks for answer anyway!

Comment: No problem :) If you found an interesting solution to your problem/question, maybe it's worth sharing here as an answer (you can even set is as accepted, since it *is* the answer to your question) so that others could possibly benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

You have just to call setVisible(true) to yours widget you want to have :

Fichier UiBinder

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

  <g:HTMLPanel>
    Hello, <g:TextBox ui:field='textBox' visible='false'/>.
  </g:HTMLPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

Fichier Java

```
public class HelloWidgetWorld extends Composite {

  interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, HelloWidgetWorld> {}
  private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

  @UiField TextBox textBox;

  public HelloWidgetWorld() {
    // sets listBox
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }

  public void restoreVisible() {
     textBox.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's obvious and it's not elegant. I need a soluthion which will do the work without even checking the ui.xml file. But thanks anyway

Comment: Or I don't understand what you want to do.